# How to get supported display refresh rates on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, debian, drm

`drmModeModeInfo` structure from [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager) contains `uint32_t vrefresh;` field, and the values are actually good there i.e. I’m getting 24-75Hz for different video modes. But refresh rates aren’t integers, they’re rational numbers, right now for my display the value is 59997/1000.

Is it possible to get the precise numbers on Linux? Or at least a floating point value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator is `drmModeModeInfo::clock * 1000`, the `clock` field is in kilohertz and we need Hz for the formula.

The denominator is the product of `drmModeModeInfo::htotal` and `drmModeModeInfo::vtotal` fields.

For better result, I simplify the rational by dividing both numerator and denominator by their greatest common divisor. For this part, I have used an [algorithm from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm#Iterative_version_in_C).

I’m not sure if current displays support signal frequencies above 2^32 Hz = 4.29 GHz, but even if they do not, future ones may do so, i.e. you better use 64-bit integer math there.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use this:

```cpp
drmModeModeInfoPtr mode = 0;
.
.
double freq = mode->clock * 1000.0f / (mode->htotal * mode->vtotal);
freq = round(freq * 1000.0f) / 1000.0f;
```